# Wordpress on Openshift

Tags: wordpress, cloud, openshift, redhat

I have installed wordpress on an openshift cluster. The problem is that when the pod falls, I have to do all the wordpress installation all over again. I used a secret where I put db_host, db_name, username and password and actually even if the node falls, wordpress even if the installation starts from scratch, once the credentials are entered it recognizes the user I had done before and takes me back to the page of login. But I want to avoid all this and I want that even if the pod falls, wordpress doesn't make me go back to the installation page, but stays on the login page.

So I would like that wordpress doesn't always go back to the installation page, but even if the pod falls, it takes me back to the login

Answer (score 0):

Your `wp-content` folder (or whatever folders that keep your Wordpress config) should map to a persistent location in OpenShift so that it’s preserved after pod restarts. You can create a Persistent Volume Claim to do that.

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't solve the problem, here is my deployment:
https://pastebin.com/vfhd5bW1

Comment: You can mount your PV to another pod to check the contents of your config file. It might be a misconfiguration in your **wp-config.php** file. Does your `$table_prefix` match your actual tables?

Comment: Everything matches, I even tried to edit my wp-config.php adding these, but the problem remains. I don't think it's a secret problem if the installation starts over.
define('DB_NAME', getenv('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME'));
define('DB_USER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASSWORD', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST') . ':' . getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));

Comment: Your environment variables in **wp-config.php** are not matching those in the Deployment YAML file. For instance, YAML file sets DB host as `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST` but your config tries to get it as `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST`